# Is this network an example of a tree topology?

Tags: networking, ethernet, topology

I have an ethernet network that is connected like the following.
Only switches and the central computer are depicted. There are more devices connected to the individual switches within the buildings, but it's not what this question is about.

What is the technically correct way to describe this network topology?
I have found the term "tree topology" online, with similar network examples. Can the following network be described as such?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tree. Just picture any of the left-side switches slightly more to the left and you should see it.

The network in your diagram is not a good setup due to chaining. Any of the left-side switches failing takes down more of the network than is necessary.

A better alternative is a central ("core") switch that all the others connect to. Any switch failing only takes down the connected nodes, except for the core switch (which you could make redudant).